# how do I install an add on from zip in xbmc 12?

Tags: kodi

http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Add-ons#How_to_install_from_zip

The wiki is pretty straighforward but those options are not present when I follow the steps in the wiki. I select this:

System --> Settings --> AddOns

All I see is a list of add ons like Youtube and Railscasts. There's no option for installing from a zip file like the wiki says. Pressing ".." just takes me to the list of AddOn types like "Album Information" and "Artist Information" etc.

The wiki looks to be out of date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Frodo (XBMC 12) assuming you have the default Confluence skin : from the home screen scroll all the way to the right and select the XBMC "System" menu. Within that, scroll down to select "Add-ons".

You are then offered a number of selections depending on what state your XBMC addons are in, but it normally includes:

- Enabled Add-ons
- Get Add-ons
- Install from zip file
- Search

If you have reached a list of addon names such as Youtube and Railscasts you have drilled down too far. Select the ".." entry at the top of the list to go back until you find the "Install from zip file" entry.